# Comparing Comma separated String in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to compare a string with comma separated values in a stored procedure.

input RANDOM string is = `"'aa','ab','ac'"`

I need something like

I need a resultant effect similar to the one below without using DYNAMIC SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.field1 LIKE %aa% OR 
table1.field1 LIKE %ab% OR 
table1.field1 LIKE %ac%
```

I cannot use find_in_set as the input string is variable and not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can approach in this way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1
WHERE
    table1.field1 REGEXP 
    REPLACE (REPLACE ("'aa','ab','ac'",'\'',''),',','|');
```

In general:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1
WHERE
    table1.field1 REGEXP 
    REPLACE (REPLACE (PUT_YOUR_INPUT_STRING_HERE,'\'',''),',','|')
```

In order to understand what's going on there the following query might lead towards that:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE("'aa','ab','ac'",'\'','') afterFirstReplace,
REPLACE(REPLACE("'aa','ab','ac'",'\'',''),',','|') afterSecondReplace;
```

---

```
afterFirstReplace               afterSecondReplace
aa,ab,ac                            aa|ab|ac
```